# How to do a daily cron to update pageviews of thousands pages from Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I would like to know what is the best way to do a daily cron to update pagesviews of each page of website without exceed the limits of API. The website have thousands of unique pages.

I'm using PHP and Google Analytics API and do a loop of all users and update the pageviews but this way is too slow and it will exceed the limit of daily quote.

Some tips to improve it?

```
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

$update = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET user_views=? WHERE user_id=?');
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM user') as $user){
    $result = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profile, '2016-01-01', 'today', 'ga:pageViews', array('filters' => 'ga:pagePath=@/' . $user['user_subdomain']));

    $views = $result[0][0] > 0 ? $result[0][0] : 0;
    $update->execute(array($views, $user['user_id']));
}
```

Comment: Look into implementing the Measurement Protocol, which has support for limited batch requests. See [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#batch-limitations). If your demands exceed the batch limitations, you can look at implementing some sort of local queueing system, that will incrementally send queue fragments to GA.

Comment: Can you give me some example to implement it?

Comment: No, I think you'll have to try it first yourself. If you can't make it work, then I'll gladly give you some pointers.

Comment: I don't know how to start, GA documentation is confused... If you can tell how to start I would be grateful.

Comment: Measurement protocol doesn't work for accessing reports data, it's used for populating analytics data. Actually, Analytics reports on data received at Measurement protocol endpoint

Answer (score 1):

you may skip splitting your request bu user page path filter but use a single request to fetch all the pageviews for all the page paths. v4 reporting API allows to fetch up to 100 000 rows with a single response. So you may have a single request to fetch the pageviews by page path and then loop through the response object to find the row containing the data for an individual user

Comment: Thanks I will do that and after I put here.